# How can I fix bootstrap opacity?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, opacity

Check the sides of the picture. I'm trying to make the background have an opacity without affecting the content I put on it. (I don't want the text to have opacity as well) But the problem all throughout is the fact that the sides of my picture aren't with opacity.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://www.elephantsdeli.com/wp-content/uploads/fly-images/1673/elephants-delicatessen-sack-lunch-order-form-hero-image.jpg-1920x1080.jpg");
  height: 50vh; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.background {
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.4)
}

.text-center {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <h1 style="font-size: 350%;" class="text-center"><b>It's Lunch-Time!</b></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `d-flex`, `align-items-center`, and `justify-content-center` instead of the custom `text-center` style. Moreover, do not set height of the row to a  `fixed` number: let it occupies the whole height of the container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://www.elephantsdeli.com/wp-content/uploads/fly-images/1673/elephants-delicatessen-sack-lunch-order-form-hero-image.jpg-1920x1080.jpg");
  height: 50vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.background {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row background h-100">
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <h1 style="font-size: 350%;"><b>It's Lunch-Time!</b></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 has your back

just add these classes `h-100` that will give you height:100% and `px-0` which will give you zero padding to the X axis

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-0 h-100">
  <div class="background">
    <h1 style="font-size: 350%;" class="text-center"><b>It's Lunch-Time!</b></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S You can also remove the `container` as long you don't use a `row` class that will break you overflow(cause row has `margin-left:-15px` and `margin-left:-15px` )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bootstrap 4 features, you have to concern its rules. Its rules say that `container` has to contain `row` and `row` has to contain `col`. In this case your markup will appear like you want.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url("https://www.elephantsdeli.com/wp-content/uploads/fly-images/1673/elephants-delicatessen-sack-lunch-order-form-hero-image.jpg-1920x1080.jpg");
  height: 50vh; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.background {
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.4)
}

.text-center {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="background col">
    <h1 style="font-size: 350%;" class="text-center"><b>It's Lunch-Time!</b></h1>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```